# База данных городов и улиц Украины

Tags: mysql

Народ, может у кого завалялись например база данных городов, улиц Украины? а то в гугле ничего не нашел.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для РФ есть такая штука как [ФИАС](http://fias.nalog.ru/Public/NewsPage.aspx), пришедшая на смену [КЛАДР](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%9B%D0%90%D0%94%D0%A0). [Вот](http://www.forum.mista.ru/topic.php?id=459427) товарищи что-то подобное для Украины, но готовое найти не могут. Хочу еще уточнить, что возможность сделать или найти такую базу зависит от задач и, соответственно, от формата представления данных. Потому что многое можно найти в разных источниках, например, существует проект [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/), из базы данных которого можно вытянуть все населенные пункты Украины и все улицы, с разбивкой по городам. Но нужно приложить некоторые усилия.

Comment: ок. спасибо буду разбираться. а то везде в основном они продаются, но хочется сэкономить

Comment: OSM бесплатный. Это первый плюс. Второй плюс - он все время уточняется. Причем как компаниями, которые им пользуются, так и простыми пользователями. Из минусов - достоверность информации может варьироваться, как в любом OpenSource проекте. Очень рекомендую ознакомиться со [справкой по OSM][1]. На самом деле справочной информации как что-либо сделать с OSM очень много. Просто нужно начать =)

[1]:https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/RU:%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0?uselang=ru

Comment: Мне лично сразу приглянулись [Osmosis][1] и [osmconvert][2]

[1]:https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis
[2]:https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert

Answer (score 1):

Можете скачать **MySQL Workbench**.
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/

Там есть БД ***world***, с огромным количеством стран и их городов. Украина присутствует. База не новая, но уже, какой-никакой фундамент

Comment: большое спасибо. возможно хватит этого.

Comment: название улиц и номера домов буду уточнять с помощью средств google map

Comment: @Firespirit,

> название улиц и номера домов буду уточнять с помощью средств google map

а смысл? Но вообще гипотетически можно координаты и адресные данные выдрать с гугля бесплатно, несмотря на то, что они их продают за деньги...

Answer (score -1):

> Народ, может у кого завалялись например база данных городов, улиц Украины? а то в гугле ничего не нашел.

Если база адресов Украины нужна для бизнес целей можете посоветовать руководству обратиться в dmsolutions - http://www.dmsolutions.com.ua/decisions/%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B4.html
у них еще есть онлайн справочник http://www.dmsolutions.com.ua/decisions/dictionaries.html
но это все платные продукты, а если бесплатно то можно и OpenStreetMap как то использовать.

Comment: Нежелательно начинать свой путь на сайте с ответов, рекламирующих некие услуги. Хотя в данном случае вроде по теме, так что как спам НЕ помечаю.